# Result of BooleanCountingFunction?

Tags: boolean-computation

Folks,
when i use BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, {v1,v2,v3}, "CNF" ] i get a neat output like:

```
(! v1 || ! v2) && (! v1 || ! v3) && (v1 || v2 || v3) && (! v2 || ! v3);
```

However, when i have >= 13 variables, i get a result like:

```
(! v1 || ! v10 || v11 || v12 || v13 || v2 || v3 || v4 || v5 || v6 || 
   v7 || v8 || v9) && (! v1 || v10 || ! v11 || v12 || v13 || v2 || 
   v3 || v4 || v5 || v6 || v7 || v8 || v9) && (! v1 || v10 || 
   v11 || ! v12 || v13 || v2 || v3 || v4 || v5 || v6 || v7 || v8 || 
   v9) && (! v1 || v10 || v11 || v12 || ! v13 || v2 || v3 || v4 || 
   v5 || v6 || v7 || v8 || v9) && (! v1 || v10 || v11 || v12 || 
   v13 || ! v2 || v3 || v4 || v5 || v6 || v7 || v8 || v9) ...
```

it is equivalent, but MUCH longer. It gives headache, when the expression is used in larger contexts.
The 'long' output is of the form :

```
(! v1 || ! v10 || v11 || v12 || v13 || v2 || v3 || v4 || v5 || v6 || v7 || v8 || v9 ) 
&& (! v1 || v10 || ! v11 || v12 || v13 || v2 || v3 || v4 || v5 || v6 || v7 || v8 || v9 ) 
&& (! v1 || v10 || v11 || ! v12 || v13 || v2 || v3 || v4 || v5 || v6 || v7 || v8 || v9)
```

and it ends with

```
&& (! v6 || v7 || v8 || ! v9) 
&& (! v7 || ! v8 || v9) 
&& (! v7 || v8 || ! v9) 
&& (! v8 || ! v9)
```

that is, the clauses are becoming shorter and shorter. When the formula has fewer that 13 variables, the result is a collection of clauses with pairwise negated variables (which assures that not two variables are true at the same time) and one big OR-clause (which assures, that at least one variable is true). 
The problem is, no way of massaging the formula brings it back to the short form.
 
The longer i think of it, the more i am convinced, that there is a bug in the general formula-rewriter; the basic formula of the BooleanCountingFunction is correct, the conversion to CNF has a problem. The result is equi-satisfiable, but much larger than needed.
Something for Mathematica 12.0.1

Comment: Is there a known shorter CNF for that case?

Comment: If you just want a shorter expression, i.e., not CNF; use `expr // Simplify`

Comment: The BooleanCountingFunction is called a 1ofN-constraint in SAT-community. The formula is true, when exactly one bit is true. The two simple ways to formulate this are:

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Might work around this using `BooleanMinimize[result,"CNF"]`.

Comment: Yo - thanks - that `BooleanMinimize[]`is a step forward.